# Empty <li> items within Rules UI

Tags: rules

[image: LI items all missing content]

Has anyone encountered behaviour similar to this and have any idea how to resolve it? I've checked the issues for Rules and can't find anything similar. I've run update.php and flushed caches, neither make a difference. Also tried completely uninstalling Rules and Rules UI and reinstalling from fresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is odd, but it's probably not rules-centric.  It looks like the system itself is in a funky state.  Have you had any other problems with white screens?  Do your mysql logs show any errors (I have seen similar problems when the `max_allowed_packet` size was too small, for example, or when the mysql server ran out of disk space.)